# How to schedule periodic delete of celery backend in Flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, celery, flower

How do I schedule periodic delete of celery backend data and flower logs such as all the data  before 48 hours will be deleted. I am using a MongoDB backend to store the celery backend data.

Answer (score 0):

Celery [doesn't support](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-expires) it as of now. You can either change the backend to one of the supported ones or you can write a custom script/celery task to delete the results manually and run it with cron/celery beat respectively. If you are already using Redis somewhere in your stack, use it as result backend too which is very common.